# Win + X, U, U not shutting down my windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, shutdown, shortcuts, multitasking

**Win + X, U, U**  is not shutting down my windows 11. Language is not the issue as i am using English. Everything is normal, The issue is that when the list opens after **Win+X** it doesn't response to any key stroke, I have to click with mouse only how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling **Underline acess keys** fixed it for me.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, but if you explained HOW to do this, this will be a more helpful answer for others having the same issue, which is a goal with this site.